# How to open new "ASP.NET Web Application" from visual studio 2015 community edition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I'm watching some ASP.NET tutorials on YouTube from earlier version of VS (2010) the instructor opened ASP.NET Web Application new project from this window:

[image]

This is additional window appears after selecting ASP.NET Web Application in VS 2015
[image]
Which item to choose to create the same project in visual studio 2015?

This lead me to another question: Are there major differences between VS 2010 and VS 2015?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is; New Asp.Net Web Application is still available in the Web Node of the template list.

Comment: there is additional window appears... I've added the details to the question,

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 only supported up to .Net 4.0.  The dialog window you have in 2015 has all the additional templates for Asp.net 4.5.2 and Asp.net 5 preview.  If you want the exact same project type, change the framework you are targeting on the first screen.

Comment: I changed the framewok to 4.0 there is only one template; 'ASP.NET Empty Web Application' is this the same as 'ASP.NET Web Application'?

Comment: Did you try it? I mean, you know what you want, you want an ASP web application, so what if you just try and compare the content. you surely still have Visual Studio 2010 rigth ?

Comment: It's an empty application;  The templates used in the 2010 version of Visual Studio may not be included in 2015, since they are completely out of date.

Comment: I have a window titled "web.config". in the tutorial: "default.aspx"?
I don't know how to open this window!

Comment: You probably want to choose Web forms on the Second window, that's what i think represent the most a classic ASP.NET web application. But if you expect making everything work with a VS 2010 tutorial but you have VS 2015... Why don't you just find a tutorial for VS 2015 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you've already chosen (Web Application).
Basically, you can choose that option and get an ASP.NET project with templates or choose 'Empty' which equivalent to 'ASP.NET Empty Web Application'. This option gives you an ASP.NET application without any template.

About the second question, you can fine some details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx).

Basically the main improvement, in VS2015, is that Microsoft has added a lot of components in order to enable mobile development via VS2015. Now, with VS2015 you can develop application for mobile like Android based system, IOS etc... Just like we could do by Android Studio.

Additionally, with VS2015 we can develop cross platform applications for Mac OS, Linux, etc...

If you are going to do so, consider installing "[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads)" on your target machine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the "Web Forms" template in the top row will be a lot closer to the VS 2010 Web Application than the "Web Application" template.
When 2010 came out, Web Forms was the de-facto web technology in VS.  MVC 2 was in its early development (now MVC 6, as in the "Web Application" template.)

The "Web Application" template you have selected uses MVC and ASP.NET5 beta, which is a whole new version of ASP.NET.  VS 2010 instructions won't work well with it at all.  Web Forms technology has moved along some since then, but it has been mostly additive.

Answer (score 0):

To create a Web application project:

1. Open Microsoft Visual Studio.
2. On the File menu, select New Project.
3. Project dialog box appears.

[image: New Project dialog box]

4. Select the Templates -> Visual C# -> Web templates group on the left.
5. Choose the ASP.NET Web Application template in the center column.
6. Name your project BasicWebApp and click the OK button.
7. Next, select the Web Forms template and click the OK button to create the project

[image: New ASP.NET Project dialog box]